# how can encrypt AES 256 with cryptojs and decrypt in swift

Tags: swift, aes, cryptoswift

I am trying to decrypt a string which is decrypted by cryptojs but not luck...I try to cryptoswift but still faileu

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("mystringforencryption", "secret");

 console.log(encrypted);
console.log("encrypted.ciphertext");
console.log(encrypted.ciphertext);
console.log(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
console.log("encrypted.key");
console.log(encrypted.key);
console.log(encrypted.key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
console.log("encrypted.iv");
console.log(encrypted.iv);
console.log(encrypted.iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
console.log("encrypted.salt");
console.log(encrypted.salt);
console.log(encrypted.salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
console.log("encrypted.padding.pad");
console.log(encrypted.padding);
```

swift part:

```
let mdata = Data(base64Encoded: "U2FsdGVkX19zC/z0w6myZ74GbapfAywMvb3Al2aD4v8=")!
let count = [UInt8](mdata).count
let mbytes = Array([UInt8](mdata)[AES.blockSize ..< count])
let mkey = "secret".md5().bytes
let miv = Array([UInt8](mdata)[0 ..< AES.blockSize])
let aes = try AES(key: mkey, blockMode: BlockMode.CBC(iv: miv))
let decrypted = try aes.decrypt(mbytes)
let mresult =  String(bytes: decrypted, encoding: .utf8)
print(mresult)
```

thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to use https://github.com/etienne-martin/WebCrypto.swift

all clear about java script side but for swift side need to include WebCrypto.js as it will load from swift to encryption and decryption.

to pass byte 64 for ecnrypted in web in swift:

```
data: Data(base64Encoded: "U2FsdGVkX1+4tZicpsJNw9TetmFZ/r+AVQu/g7WPq7Zeen/z2RWfGmlluOeKZgpy", options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

full example:

**swift**

```
 crypto.decrypt(data: Data(base64Encoded: "U2FsdGVkX1+4tZicpsJNw9TetmFZ/r+AVQu/g7WPq7Zeen/z2RWfGmlluOeKZgpy", options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!, password: password, callback: {(decrypted: Data?, error: Error?) in
                print(String(data: decrypted!, encoding: .utf8)!)
            })
```

**javascript**

```
WebCrypto.encrypt({
        data: input,
        password: password,
        callback: function(response){
            if( !response.error ){
                console.log("encrypt base64")
                console.log(response.result);
            }else{
                console.error(response.error);
            }
        }
    });
```